how to disable showing Time & Source of the log in each line in Restify application?
I'm working a NodeJS application that has been built using Restify framework. It uses Winston 3.13.0 package for logging. In the logs I observed that Time & Source of the log gets appended with every line. For example,
18:37:00 0|server  | {"level":"info", "message":"some info message", "timestamp":"2024-05-22 06:37:00.703 PM"} 

As you can see in the above example, 18:37:00 0|server  |  got appended with the log. <Time> 0| <source>  | - source = server/ pm2
Is it possible to get rid of this prefix and print only the json log object? i.e,
{"level":"info", "message":"some info message", "timestamp":"2024-05-22 06:37:00.703 PM"} 

Here is my code for Winston logger -
const winston = require('winston')
const { combine, timestamp, colorize, align, json, errors, printf } = winston.format

// JSON format with timestamp
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'debug',

  format: combine(
    errors({ stack: true }),
    timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.SSS A' }),
    json(),
    align(),
    colorize({ all: true })
  ),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'my-service' },
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(), // Output logs to the console
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new winston.transports.Console()
  ],
  rejectionHandlers: [
    new winston.transports.Console()
  ],
})

module.exports = logger

I believe <Time> 0| <source>  | text is getting appended by Restify framework. I'm not sure though.
